# Operators precedence/pre-post operators

Tags: c, operators

In running the below code, I got 25 which really puzzles me...any explanation?
I was expecting 20 (4 times 5 or 5 times 4)

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int a=3; int res=++a*(a++ +1);
    printf("res= %d", res);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The program has undefined behavior and could print just about anything or nothing. If you use gcc or clang, add the compiler options `-Wsequence-point -Werror` to avoid making programs like this. See the _Undefined behavior_ chapter in [Order of evaluation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/eval_order)

Comment: Thank you Ted for the answer and reference

Comment: If you want to have a laugh, `(a++)*(a++ + 1)` evaluates to 15!